# Failed to resolve : com.android.support:design:26.0.0

Tags: android, material-design

I cannot include material design library in my project

**This is my build.gradle file**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abdelmagied.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
}
```

**Every time I Sync it gives me this error:**

> Failed To resolve:com.android.support:design:26.0.0

Comment: Can you try adding a repository section to your build.gradle such as this. repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have downloaded the support libraries from your SDK Manager (in OSX: Tools > Android > SDK Manager --> SDK Tools Tab)

Comment: This worked for me!! Thanks Julian!